# What are the odds of the same group of 4 being drawn twice from a pool of 16?

Tags: probability

Let's say we have 16 participants who are randomly split into 4 groups of 4.

I have two separate questions:

1) What are the odds of a pre-selected group of 4 being one of the groups?

2) If two draws were performed, what are the odds of one of the same group being formed twice?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

1.
You can look at it as computing the probability that one of the 4, two of the 4, etc. are together. Now imagine you have 16 slots a person can end up in (4 in each group). Having one person out of those four in some group is a sure event. Now you want a second person to be in the same group, where 3 slots are left: that's 3/15. Third person ... 2/14. Fourth ... 1/13.

Now you just multiply it together (independent events):
$$
1*3/15*2/14*1/13 = 6/2730‬ = 1/455
$$

2.
So if we assume that you don't care which group will be formed twice, then first time there will be 4 random groups formed and you want at least one of them to repeat. Basically a similar situation as in the 1. case but you now have four possible groups that are all permissible.
**Edit:** The expression is more complex than what I originally wrote (see David K's comment). We'd need to subtract the "scenarios" that were accounted for more than one time. I'll leave it unanswered for now.

Comment: The first part is correct, but the second result is the _expected number_ of groups that are chosen again the second time. This includes cases in which two groups repeat, which are counted with twice the weight of cases where only one group repeats, so you get a larger result than the simple probability that at least one group repeats.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the comment. I've removed the result.

Comment: It seems like an application of Inclusion-Exclusion.